# How to validate api parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to validate if a parameter is null in asp .net core 2.1. In the below example the "IsValid" returns true.

This is the code we use

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> test([BindRequired, FromQuery]string id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

TestUrl I use: testurl/api/test and Still ModelState.IsValid returns true

Comment: What is the complete URL you are using to test with?

Comment: https://testurl/api/test?id=123 is the test URL

Comment: Why would you expect it to return `false`? That looks valid to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem here.
If you are using "testurl/api/test?id=123", then your parameter is *not* null, in fact it's a perfectly valid integer (123), and therefore the ModelState.IsValid returns true.

Comment: yes you are right, my bad. for testing I used the "testurl/api/tes"t and still ModelState.IsValid returns true